# Quel est le mot français pour les plantes épineuses, piquantes ou posoineuses?

Tags: traduction, terminologie, botanique

quel est le mot français pour les plantes épineuses, piquantes ou posoineuses?

entre les années 1920 et 1980, le mot "***weed***" était utilisé par les Américains pour désigner les plantes indésirables.

> - les mauvaises herbes sont des plantes qui se propagent rapidement et ont de nombreux enfants.
> - les ***weeds*** sont des légumes-feuilles vénéneux ou des plantes feuillues au goût amer.
> - les ***weeds***, arbustes, buissons et arbres courts avec des feuilles pointues et des épines, comme les chardons..

quand j'utilise un ordinateur électronique pour traduire l'anglais en français, l'ordinateur électronique écrit que le mot mauvaise herbe est "herbe".

les français détestent-ils l'herbe ? quelle expression ou quel mot les français utilisent-ils le plus souvent pour les plantes au mauvais goût couvertes d'épines et d'épines qui ont beaucoup d'enfants ?

Comment: "Mauvaise herbe" en général. Plutôt parce que ces herbes sont indésirables. On ne mange pas vraiment l'herbe. Les herbes de Provence, oui, mais l'herbe tout court, c'est plutôt pour le bétail.

Comment: Plutôt que "poisoneuses": vénéneuses.

Comment: On mange certaines herbes ou plantes herbacées, telles que les orties: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortie#Utilisation_alimentaire.

Comment: I think you should ask your questions in English, some parts of your question are unclear or don't make a whole lot of sense. It's perfectly OK to ask in English and it would make it clearer for us and easier for you to write :)

Answer (score 1):

Les **adventices** sont des plantes dont la croissance au jardin ou dans les champs est considérée comme indésirable. D'une manière plus populaire, on parlerait de 'mauvaises herbes'. Il peut donc s'agir de plantes endémiques, locales ou bien introduites par l'homme et dont le contrôle n'est plus possible à l'échelle nationale. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventice

Il n' a pas de nom générique pour les plantes toxiques ou vénéneuses, ni pour Les plantes piquantes ou épineuses, ni pour l'ensemble des plantes invasives.

Answer (score 0):

Comme le dit Graffito, je ne trouve pas de nom pour les plantes vénéneuses.
Pour les plantes piquantes ou épineuses, on parlerait effectivement de « mauvaises herbes ».
Je pense aussi à « broussailles » ou « chiendent ».
En provençal (salonais en particulier), on parlerait de « [bordille](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bordille) », où la désignation (ordure, par exemple au bord des ruisseaux) se confond avec l'insulte (personne méprisable).